# Using a pointer and did not use `free()` and no memory leaks

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, free, address-sanitizer

In my program I have used `malloc()` and pointer but I did not use `free()` to free those memory, I have compiled with `-fsanitize=address` flag but it is saying there is no memory leaks. As far as I know if I allocate memory I also have to free the memory in the end of the program otherwise there will be memory leaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void print2D(int rowSize, int **cols_size, int **arr) {

    for(int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < (*cols_size)[i]; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int** make2D(int rowSize, int **colSize) {

    int** arr = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * rowSize);

    for(int i=0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    }

    *colSize = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int*) * 2);

    (*colSize)[0] = 2;
    (*colSize)[1] = 2;

    arr[0][0] = 1;
    arr[0][1] = 2;

    arr[1][0] = 3;
    arr[1][1] = 4;

    return arr;
}

int main() {

    int **colSize;
    int rowSize = 2;

    int** arr = make2D(rowSize, colSize);

    print2D(rowSize, colSize, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and ran it with `gcc -o wow -fsanitize=address wow.c && ./wow`

How so there is no memory leaks? Am I missing something?

## update

first time I compiled and ran using `wsl (debian 10)` and `fsanitize=address` failed to detect memory leaks

But when I compiled and ran with `Arch 5.19` it detected `DEADLYSIGNAL`. Now why is that?

Comment: I'm not very familier with gcc, but I suppose `-fsanitize=address` doesn't check for memory leaks

Comment: That option checks that you don't misuse memory.  You need `-fsanitize=leaks` to look for leaks, IIRC.

Comment: @Jabberwocky check this link 
https://www.osc.edu/resources/getting_started/howto/howto_use_address_sanitizer.

@JonathanLeffler same thing with `fsanitize=leak`

Comment: If I add the `-static-libasan` flag as mentioned in your link it gives me errors about memory leaks: https://godbolt.org/z/r9Mv17rsj

Comment: @altair00 This statement * colSize = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int*) * 2); invokes undefined behavior because the pointer colSize does not point to a valid object.

Comment: You should consider warnings before looking for memory leaks.
You are sending colSize to the make2D function without initializing it. Maybe it's the colSize address you wanted to send instead.

Comment: It is a question of semantics whether unfreed dynamically allocated memory that is still accessible to the program when it exits should be considered leaked.  Certainly many occurrences of this pattern are benign, and perhaps even desirable for code clarity.  The OS can be expected to reclaim the program's memory when it terminates, whether freed or not.  Memory that is leaked prior to program termination, especially by code that is executed many times, is the primary area of concern when it comes to memory leaks.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You mean, the use of uninitialized  `colSize` in the line `int** arr = make2D(rowSize, colSize);` invokes undefined behavior. :)

Comment: @Kaz What I mean I have described clear.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow can you please read the updated part in the question and can you explain the behaviour,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler not only reports the leak (if the program manages to avoid a SIGSEGV) but that your program exhibits undefined behaviour.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsanitize=address a.c -o a && ./a
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:42:17: warning: ‘colSize’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   42 |     int** arr = make2D(rowSize, colSize);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 2
3 4

=================================================================
==187==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fda63d72808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x5594afb0c407 in make2D (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x1407)
    #2 0x5594afb0c6d6 in main (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x16d6)
    #3 0x7fda63a97082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 2 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fda63d72808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x5594afb0c433 in make2D (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x1433)
    #2 0x5594afb0c6d6 in main (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x16d6)
    #3 0x7fda63a97082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 32 byte(s) leaked in 3 allocation(s).
```

To fix the undefined behaviour, replace

```c
int **colSize;
int rowSize = 2;

int** arr = make2D(rowSize, colSize);

print2D(rowSize, colSize, arr);
```

with

```c
int *colSize;
int rowSize = 2;

int** arr = make2D(rowSize, &colSize);

print2D(rowSize, &colSize, arr);
```

Then you get

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsanitize=address a.c -o a && ./a
1 2
3 4

=================================================================
==249==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fd485c86808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x55e3c49a8447 in make2D (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x1447)
    #2 0x55e3c49a8797 in main (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x1797)
    #3 0x7fd4859ab082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fd485c86808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x55e3c49a84af in make2D (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x14af)
    #2 0x55e3c49a8797 in main (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x1797)
    #3 0x7fd4859ab082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

Indirect leak of 16 byte(s) in 2 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fd485c86808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x55e3c49a8473 in make2D (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x1473)
    #2 0x55e3c49a8797 in main (/tmp/ikegami/a/a+0x1797)
    #3 0x7fd4859ab082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 48 byte(s) leaked in 4 allocation(s).
```

---

You should change `print2D` to take `const int *cols_size` instead of `int **cols_size`. There's no need for the indirection.

Comment: This summay is shown after fixing the UB isn't it? In that case it would be good to point it out so that the OP can deduce that the leak is not shown due to a previous segfault.

Comment: @David Ranieri Re "*This summay is shown after fixing the UB isn't it?*", No. You can clearly see the UB is still present from the warning bringing your attention to the UB.

Comment: oops, strange, using your command it shows _AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==149484==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x556d47bdf499 bp 0x7ffd2662c090 sp 0x7ffd2662c060 T0)_ it only shows the same summary that you present after applying the fix to the UB

Comment: @David Ranieri, That's the thing with UB. You don't always get the same thing :)

Comment: _You don't always get the same thing :)_ yeah, thats true :)

Comment: @David Ranieri, I have made changes to my answer based on your feedback.

Comment: @ikegami please read the updated part in the question and if you have any clue about that behavior do tell